# Using C-h inside the box to delete character [company-mode]

Tags: company-mode

I am using `company-mode` for word suggestions.

In `company-mode`, when I use `C-h` instead of deleting a character it says `No documentation available`.

---

I have added following lines to `.emacs`, which did not solve it.

```
(add-hook 'after-init-hook 'global-company-mode)
(with-eval-after-load "company"
  (define-key company-search-map (kbd "C-h") #'company-search-delete-char))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your setting looks valid, but since it is not doing, what you expect, you probably changed the wrong keymap.

exchange your `(define-key...` line by:

```
(define-key company-active-map (kbd "C-h") nil)
```

if you have set up your emacs to normaly delete chars with `C-h`
or

```
(define-key company-active-map (kbd "C-h") #'backward-delete-char)
```

otherwise.

Note: you can still access the help feature of company by using `F1` key.